# How to access Pgadmin3 on Ubuntu - OpenErp

Tags: postgresql, odoo, pgadmin

On windows the allinone package automatically installs the pgadmin3 manager.

On Ubuntu i've installed the all-in-one .deb package of openerp 7, it comes with the postgresql db on it, but i just can't figure out how to launch it...

On running the command `find / -name pgadmin3` it throws me a lot of folders on the /opt/openerp installation but still doesn't tell me where the database manager is.

Should i install it apart? Be aware that the all-in-one .deb package already has postgresql, i wouldn't like to override some configuration on the server.

EDIT:

I ran the command as `sudo find / -name pgadmin3` it doesn't finds anything, it is maybe possible that the all-in-one .deb package doesn't comes with it? (pgadmin3) Just the postgresql server without the pgadmin3 manager?

Answer (score 1):

It indeed needed to be installed, now i can access it, but the problem now is how to configure it to communicate with the openerp db.

I'm adding the new server connection, but it gives me errors with the user and password, i don't know if the user is `openpg` with password `openpgpwd` or maybe user `openerp` password `admin`?

Comment: Solved! I followed a tutorial in the doc.openerp.com/trunk/ section, thanks!